# How to contr URL access by different user?

Tags: django

I am new to django.In my project,I have many users,how to control the Url access by different user?
eg:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'man/dash/(?P<base>[0-9]{8})/$', man_dash ,name='man_dash')
]
```

The url can access By User A and B has no permisson.
I will appreciate it if someone can give me a instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be done on URL level, but view level. In the view that the URL redirects to, you can check if the user has the permissions he/she needs and then either return a site or return a 404 page or 403 forbidden page.

example:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed

class MyView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'sth.html'

     def get(self, request, **kwargs):
         if request.user.is_superuser():
             return super().get(request, **kwargs)

         return HttpResponseNotAllowed()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def my_check(user):
    return user.username == 'A'

@user_passes_test(my_check)
def man_dash(request):
```

Comment: Function-based views are deprecated from 1.10, please don't encourage using them. :)

Comment: But they're so simple and beautiful : (

Comment: Only for limited use cases... I do use them myself for simple AJAX views for example, but all in all I get the reason for deprecating them. It's a slippery slope if you start using them too much, it will shoot you in the leg.

Comment: @makaveli Wait, what!? Function-based views are by no means deprecated. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @knbk Sorry, my bad, I cited a coworker without checking the facts. knbk is right: they aren't deprecated and no one is planning to deprecate them either.